# How to create an Eevee-only light?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

I have a scene that I'm trying to make work in both Eevee and Cycles. When rendering with Eevee, I need some additional light objects to fake some of the lighting. Is there a good way to set those lights to be Eevee-only so that they aren't rendered when using Cycles?

Comment: You could add a collection with just eevee lights in it.  That way you could toggle them all off in the render.   Or if you really wanted to do things differently, you could create a new scene at the top of your outliner.  It could have all the same objects, but just Eeevee lights and settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Summary: setup the light as desired in Eevee then switch to Cycles and disconnect its Light Shader Node output (which is ignored by Eevee).

Steps:

1. Add the light in Eevee
2. Switch to "Cycles" Render Engine in the Render Properties panel
3. Select the light in the Outliner and in the Light properties, click "Use Nodes"
4. Go to the Shader Node Editor
5. disconnect the Surface input socket from the Light Output node
6. switch back to Eevee mode in the Render Properties panel

[image]

Comment: Nice trick. Though the OP need a light that works on eevee only, not cycles only.

Comment: This is Eevee only. The light is disabled in Cycles by disconnecting the Surface input of the Light Output node.

Comment: That isn't what I understand when I read your first line :o

Comment: ok let me rephrase... and let me know if that's clearer!

Comment: crystal clear now, thanks 

Comment: This works! Although I am worried that it will break if/when Eevee adds supports for lighting nodes.

Comment: indeed, in which case you would hopefully have to switch to @l0lock version.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the lamp to use nodes, you can specify in the `Light Output` node for which render engine it will be used. By default, it is set to `All`, so what you can do is to duplicate your node tree, have one `Light Output` for each render engine, and set the Cycles one to use a zero strength `Emission` shader. Like so:

[image: example]

Comment: Have you tried it? Eevee doesn't support nodes on lights

Comment: This "intuitively" should work but it does not. Check it out.

Comment: It works in 2.93 but not on 3.0, I guess that's a bug :/

Comment: This is not a bug. It doesn't work because EEVEE ignores nodes in lights. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/limitations.html

Comment: Interesting, because [I have been using this trick for a while now](https://i.imgur.com/Wibmy6I.gif). I guess I will have to make sur to not open my old projects on v3  The manual does say it's not supported "as of now" so hopefully it will be restored at some point!

Comment: @L0Lock Technically, your picture works, but explanation why is wrong. You are showing the same trick that Bruno shows. Try to delete two bottom nodes, and you will get the same result (or try to set red and green colors).

Answer (score 2):

You can disable objects and lights in the Object data tab → Visibility → Ray Visibility (Uncheck all items in the list):

[image]

These options only affects on Cycles, and they are available only as long as the Cycles is active.